# Using "versus" in a title

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I use capital letters in the first word of titles except (the, in, on, etc.). I am now using the word `versus` in a title. does the first letter needs to be capitalized

> Method-A Versus Method-B

or

> Method-A versus Method-B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepositions are generally capitalized if they are used adverbially or adjectively. Here, the word *versus* is not used that way but it is merely a preposition. Thus, I would not capitalize it:

> Method A versus Method B

Alternatively,

> Method A v Method B (BrE without a period) 
>  Method A vs. Method B (AmE with a period)

Also,

> Method A vs. Method B (AmE with a period) 
>  Method A vs Method B (BrE without a period)

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer. It depends entirely on which style guide you follow.

If you are writing for a specific institution, find out what style guide they normally adhere to and follow that one.

For instance, both the *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association* and the *Associated Press Stylebook* would punctuate it as:

> Method-A Versus Method-B

Meanwhile, *The Chicago Manual of Style* and the *MLA Style Manual* would punctuate it as:

> Method-A versus Method-B

Even within those *general* guidelines, each style guide might provide variations.

One of several websites that lets you see different title punctuation is [Capitalize My Title](https://capitalizemytitle.com/).

If you are not writing for anybody other than yourself, simply pick what looks best to you. (Or pick a style guide that appeals to you most.) But whatever you do, make sure that you apply the style consistently.